# Insert diario en SQL Server con datos de otra tabla de otro servidor

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo que hacer un 'job' de SQL Server programado para todos los días a las 10 de la mañana. El Trabajo se basaría en volcar los datos de una tabla de una base de datos de un servidor en otras 2 tablas (con operaciones de por medio) en otra base de datos de otro servidor.

No tengo claro cómo recorrer todos los registros, tengo entendido que bucles `for` y `foreach` no existen en SQL. El acceso a otros servidores creo tenerlo controlado. Están vinculados y me deja acceder a sus datos aunque no insertar (imagino que sea por tratarse de otro servidor, estará a modo solo lectura, no lo sé). La idea sería algo así:

```
--TABLA_FINAL1
INSERT INTO [BDFINAL].[dbo].[TABLA_FINAL1]
SELECT
    campo1_tablaDN16,
    campo1_tablaDN16,
    'Parametro fijo',
    @ParametroCalculado,
    campo1_tablaDN16,
    ...(otros)
FROM [192.168.1.15].[BD_BASE].[dbo].[TABLA_BASE];


--TABLA_FINAL2
INSERT INTO [BDFINAL].[dbo].[TABLA_FINAL2]
SELECT
    campo1_tablaDN16,
    campo1_tablaDN16,
    'Parametro fijo',
    @ParametroCalculado,
    campo1_tablaDN16,
    ...(otros)
FROM [192.168.1.15].[BD_BASE].[dbo].[TABLA_BASE];
```

No sé si la sintaxis sería correcta, desde luego me marca error en los campos y eso serviría si fuese un solo registro, la idea sería volcar todos (los que cumplan cierta condición). ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: te marca algún mensaje de error?, yo creo que puede ser seguridad, ya que debe de poderse realizar un select insert tal como lo estas haciendo.

Answer (score 1):

Después de mucho buscar resulta que si se pueden hacer loops en sql server:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < cnt_total
BEGIN
   {...statements...}
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
introducir el código aquí
```

Answer (score 1):

Depende de donde ejecutes el JOB, debes hacer una cosa u otra, aunque solo cambia la primera linea

```
INSERT [TABLA_FINAL1]
SELECT
campo1_tablaDN16,
campo1_tablaDN16,
'Parametro fijo',
@ParametroCalculado,
campo1_tablaDN16,
...(otros)
FROM [192.168.1.15].[BD_BASE].[dbo].[TABLA_BASE];
```

En caso de ejecutar el job en la tabla origen sería

```
INSERT [IP SERVIDOR FINAL].[BD_BASE].[dbo].[TABLA_FINAL1]
SELECT
campo1_tablaDN16,
campo1_tablaDN16,
'Parametro fijo',
@ParametroCalculado,
campo1_tablaDN16,
...(otros)
FROM [TABLA_BASE];
```

y si quieres filtrar por fechas, yo te recomendaría usar esta conversión

```
CONVERT(varchar, fecha filtro,111) = CONVERT(varchar, getdate()-1,111)
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba con esto

```
INSERT INTO [BDFINAL].[dbo].[TABLA_FINAL2]
SELECT
    campo1_tablaDN16,
    campo1_tablaDN16,
    'Parametro fijo',
    @ParametroCalculado,
    campo1_tablaDN16,
    ...(otros)
FROM [192.168.1.15].[BD_BASE].[dbo].[TABLA_BASE]
where (getdate()-1)
Ojo si tu tabla tiene el dia puedes hacerlo asi
INSERT INTO [BDFINAL].[dbo].[TABLA_FINAL2]
SELECT
    campo1_tablaDN16,
    campo1_tablaDN16,
    'Parametro fijo',
    @ParametroCalculado,
    campo1_tablaDN16,
    ...(otros)
FROM [192.168.1.15].[BD_BASE].[dbo].[TABLA_BASE]
where columna_fecha_ayer = (getdate()-1)
```